# how to handle navigation inside build method in dart flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an application where I want to implement finger authentication. I have written the classes for authentication is working fine.
Now the scenario is, when the app starts it loads login page where I have a form. I want to check for finger print authentication first if it is successful then I want to switch to home page otherwise show the login form if not successful.
Here is my code:

```
 final LocalAuthenticationService _localAuth = locator<LocalAuthenticationService>();
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   _localAuth.authenticate().then((result){
       if(result)
         Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.HomePage);
   });
   return return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(image: _builSplashBackgroundImage()),
        child: _buildLoginForm()
   );
}
```

I get this error when I navigate to homepage: Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

Comment: try to call `_localAuth` after the layout is built using https://pub.dev/packages/after_layout

Comment: I am getting the same error after using "AfterLayoutMixin":

@override
  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext aflContext) {
     if(widget.settings.isFingerPrintLoginEnabled)
      authenticate(aflContext);
  }

  void authenticate(BuildContext authContext)async{
    await _localAuth.authenticate();
    if(_localAuth.isAuthenticated)  
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(authContext, Routes.HomePage);
  }

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. Just implement it like this using FutureBuilder

```
final LocalAuthenticationService _localAuth = locator<LocalAuthenticationService>();


@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
    body:  FutureBuilder( 
future: _localAuth.authenticate,
builder:(ctx, snapshot)=>!snapshot.hasData? CircularProgressIndicator():
snapshot.data == true?Routes.HomePage:
 Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(image: _builSplashBackgroundImage()),
        child: _buildLoginForm()
   )));
}
```

This code will show a progressbar when loading user's connection state.
You can learn more [Here](https://medium.com/flutterpub/future-builder-flutter-part-one-14dec0c229a1)  about FutureBuilder

Comment: We can't return Routes.HomePage as it expects a widget not a string

Comment: you can call the page where  Routes.HomePage is pointing to... like HomePage() because it is a Widget it can be used anywhere widget can be used